# PivotTable Name Purpose

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, named-ranges

In the PivotTable Analyze tab, you are given the option to give a PivotTable a name, much like a regular table. However, unlike a regular table, this name may not be referenced in any formulas (such as GETPIVOTDATA where one of the inputs is "pivot_table") and does not appear in name manager.

Can anyone tell me the purpose of giving a pivot table a name, then? I have been searching and can't find a reason. Is there a reason that pivot table names can't have the same functionality as a regular table name? Adding that consistency to Excel would make building formulas easier and makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons (there may be others):

1. You have several pivot tables in the Workbook and you are programmatically creating them using VBA or some other language.
2. When attaching slicers to more than one pivot table and if you have many pivot tables, it can be useful to be able to easily distinguish their names from one another in the Report Connections dialog.

This:

[image]

Or this:

[image]